# Tangent lines to 2 surafces in multivariable calculus

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Find the equation of the unique line that is tangent to the two surfaces $x^2 + y^2 + 2z^2 = 4$ and $z = e$^$(x-y)$ at the point $(1,1,1)$.

I am not quite sure how to go about trying to solve this problem. I thought about maybe plugging in the $z = e$^$(x-y)$ into $z$ for the other equation and then finding the tangent line to that equation at $(1,1,1)$. But I don't think that will quite work. My teacher gave us a hint which was to try to describe the surfaces as level sets. I tried writing out the level sets. This would make the first equation into $x^2 + y^2 + 2c^2 = 4$ and the second into $c = e$^$(x-y)$. But honestly, I'm really not sure what good that does me. Is it true to say that the tangent line to both of the level sets will be the same as the tangent line of the original functions? If so, then I can get y by itself for both functions and try to use calc I skills to solve. But again, I don't think this method will work. Does anyone have a solution or a better way for me to attack this problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You're given two functions, and a point common to them.

For each function, you can calculate the gradient at that point.

- What is the relationship of the gradient to the surface?  (Hint: It's the antonym of *abnormal*.)
- Any tangent to the surface must be perpendicular to the normal vector at that point.  What expression must be satisfied for two vectors to be perpendicular to each other?
- Write down these two expressions, one for each surface, and solve.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the help. I don't think I'm doing it right still though.

I got the gradient of the first function as $∇f(x,y,z) = 2x + 2y + 4z$ and the second gradient as $∇g(x,y) = e$^$(x-y) - e$^$(x-y) = 0$.

I'm assuming the condition you are talking about is that the dot product of the two vectors should be equal to zero? If so then $<0,2x+2y+4z> = 0$?

Comment: Actually, void some of what I said. Making these vectors, $∇f(x,y,z) = (2x, 2y, 4z)$ and $∇g(x,y,z) = (e^(x−y), -e^(x−y), -1)$. Evaluated at $(1,1,1)$, I'd get $(2,2,4)$ and $(1,-1,-1)$ respectively. Right?

Comment: Is the non-parametric answer $x+3y+5z=9?$ That's what I got it as for a final answer.

Comment: $x+3y+5z=9$ is a plane.  If your vector is $(a,b,c)$ then the two dot products equaling zero (as per your first comment) you solve $a-b-c=0$ and $a+b+2c=0$.  (My solution was wrong, so I deleted it.)

Comment: Okay I get what you're doing. But if I set the two equations equal to eachother, I get 3b+5c = 0. If I try to solve without setting them equal to eachother, there aren't enough equations to actually solve for all of the variables. Plus, I'm not really sure where to go from there anyways. Will the answer be the tangent vector plus some intercept?